# Magento2 in How to Remove options and price section on configurable product by custom module?

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, magento2.2, magento2.2.3

I want to Remove options and price section on the configurable product by the custom module.

[image]

I have one configurable product attribute yes/no type. If select yes then remove this section if no select then no need to remove.

Ref-

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.test" template="Magento_Catalog::test.phtml" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote small module please see, you can check also on github link at the bottom.

1. Create module app/etc/YourVendor/ModulName/
2. Add file app/etc/YourVendor/ModulName/registration.php

   ```
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
       'YourVendor_ModulName',
       __DIR__
   );
   ```
3. create file in app/etc/YourVendor/ModulName/etc/module.xml

   ```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <!--
   /**
    * @copyright: Copyright © 2018 You All rights reserved.
    * @author   : your details
    */
   -->
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <module name="YourVendor_ModulName" setup_version="0.0.1" />
   </config>
   ```

4. create file in app/etc/YourVendor/ModulName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!--
   /**
    * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */
   -->
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <attribute name="class" value="page-product-configurable"/>
           <referenceBlock name="head.components">
               <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="configurableproduct_product_view_head_components" template="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::js/components.phtml"/>
           </referenceBlock>
           <referenceContainer name="product.info.type">
               <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/type/default.phtml"/>
               <container name="product.info.configurable.extra" after="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data_extra" label="Product Extra Info">
                   <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Stockqty\Type\Configurable" name="product.info.configurable.extra.catalog_inventory_stockqty_composite" template="Magento_CatalogInventory::stockqty/composite.phtml"/>
               </container>
           </referenceContainer>
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper" remove="true"/>

   <referenceBlock name="product.info.price" remove="true"/>

       </body>
   </page>
   ```

You can also download it from github:
https://github.com/btekbtek/Magento2-module-removeconf

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have one configurable product attribute yes/no type. If select yes then remove else keep it as.

Comment: So you want remove attributes after selection?

Comment: No no- Extample - one custom attribute - is_notdisplay_options - values yes/no.. If I am select yes then options not display else display

Comment: and this option should be in the backend?

Comment: yes it's backend product attribute